# Attribute error message is getting displayed while performing any action

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, pytest

I am trying to generate allure report using  Python Selenium framework.

On executing the command from CMD:

```
pytest --alluredir= /path for report directory
```

Error message:

> severities = [x.value for x in list(allure.severity_level)]
>   AttributeError: module 'allure' has no attribute 'severity_level'
>    is getting displayed

Comment: Run `python -c "import allure; print(allure.__file__)"`, what output do you get?

Comment: I keep getting the same issue. @hoefling, I ran your script line above and it gives me the path to the init file. Can you help?

Comment: @PraveenPandey can you post the complete file path?

Comment: I have made the problem statement elaborate here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57851526/not-able-to-generate-allure-report-in-pytest-getting-attributeerror-module-a#comment102130836_57851526 Can you please check