# Not able to generate allure report in pytest. Getting 'AttributeError: module 'allure' has no attribute 'severity_level''

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest, allure

I have 2 files-

conftest.py:

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver

driver = None

@pytest.fixture(autouse = True)
def browserSetAndClose():
    global driver

    EXE_PATH = r'C:\Users\1602746\Softwares\chromedriver.exe'
    chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chromeOptions.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = EXE_PATH, options = 
    chromeOptions, desired_capabilities = chromeOptions.to_capabilities())
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get('http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/')

    yield driver
    driver.quit()
```

test_ABTesting.py:

```
import pytest
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

import conftest

@pytest.fixture
def goToABTestingPage():
    wait = WebDriverWait(conftest.driver, 10)
    wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[starts-with(@href, '/abtest')]"))).click()


def test_abTest_header(goToABTestingPage):
    a = conftest.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("h3").text
    assert 'A/B Test' in a

def test_abTest_paragraph(goToABTestingPage):
    a = conftest.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[contains(text(),'Also known as split testing. This is a way in which businesses are able to simultaneously test and learn different versions of a page to see which text and/or functionality works best towards a desired outcome (e.g. a user action such as a click-through).')]").text
    assert 'Also known as split testing. This is a way in which businesses are able to simultaneously test and learn different versions of a page to see which text and/or functionality works best towards a desired outcome (e.g. a user action such as a click-through).' in a
```

I also have allure libraries added. Now I am running my 2 test cases by running the command:

> pytest test_ABTesting.py

I keep getting this error:

> AttributeError: module 'allure' has no attribute 'severity_level'

Not sure what it means.

Comment: I also found an unanswered similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57722651/attribute-error-message-is-getting-displayed-while-performing-any-action

Comment: Any luck @hoefling?